# How to use the verb trawl in the fishing sense

Tags: word-usage

I think the verb trawl is used more in sense of the process of fishing and mostly followed by where the fishing process takes place and in this usage it sounds as if fishermen tried to catch fish in a place but it is not clear if they succeed.

I'd like to ask if it  sounds natural if I say:

> Fishermen trawled at least 100 kg of fish..

or

> Fishermen trawled an amount of fish that they have never before at
>   this time of year.

Maybe I can use the verb catch but I just want to know if I can use the verb trawl because it gives information as to how the fish is caught but I am not sure the verbs catch and trawl can be synonym in this sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sentence "fishermen trawled at least 100 kg of fish" is fine.

However, "to trawl" often describes the *process* of fishing, rather than actually catching the fish, and it may sound more natural to say "trawl *for* fish" than "trawl *a* fish".

Perhaps you would prefer to say something along the lines of:

> The fishermen caught more fish than they'd ever caught before during that time of year.

You can use trawler (as a noun) to describe the boat, so you could also say:

> The trawlers pulled in at least 100kg of fish

where "pulled in" is a colloquial way of saying "caught."

---

I thought I'd correct your second sentence's grammar (your first sentence is fine):

> Fishermen trawled an amount of fish that they had never trawled before at this time of year.

You need a verb between "never" and "before." Also, use 'had' instead of 'have' because *now* they have trawled that many fish, it's just that they **had**n't up until now.

More idiomatically perhaps:

> Fisherman trawled more fish than ever before for this time of year

Comment: Some dictionaries provide definitions that suggest _trawl_ could be used in this way. See [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/trawl), for example, which includes these definitions: _To catch (fish) with a trawl; To catch or take with a trawl-net._ I found this sample usage in a thesis: _It was near the mouth of this river in 1938 that Captain Hendrik Goosen trawled a catch of fish_.

Comment: He trawled a *catch*.

Comment: @theonlygusti - If you don't like Wordnik, I can use Def 3 from the OED: _trans. To catch or take with a trawl or trawl-net._ But you and I both seem to agree that it's not a common usage.

Answer (score 1):

> Fishermen trawled at least 100 kg of fish.

There is nothing wrong with this sentence, although I haven't heard the verb *trawl* used that way very often. If you wanted to use *caught* yet still convey the additional information, you could say:

> Fishermen caught at least 100 kg of fish while trawling.

or:

> Fishermen went trawling and caught at least 100 kg of fish.

As for your second sentence, I'd reword it as follows:

> Fishermen trawled **more** fish **than they ever have before** at this time of year.